# Add the values from input and store them in an array on a button click using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

> I want to create an exact component like this but with using react useState hook, but I am confused as I am new to react-hooks please help me

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Input2 extends Component {
  state = {
    cart: []
  };

  saveInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  addNewItem = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        cart: [...prevState.cart, prevState.input],
      }));
    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.saveInput}
        />
        <button onClick={this.addNewItem}> Add Item </button>
        <ol>
          {this.state.cart.map((Items, Index) => {
            return <li key={Index}> {Items}</li>
          })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your effort so far and where you are facing problems with hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exchange the state for two hooks:

```
const Input2 = props => {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState([]);

  saveInput = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  addNewItem = () => {
    setCart(prevState => [...prevState, input]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={saveInput} />
      <button onClick={addNewItem}> Add Item </button>
      <ol>
        {cart.map((Items, Index) => (
          <li key={Index}> {Items}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input2;
```